# Windows live mail

Tags: windows-7

I have started to experience issues with Windows Live Mail. I cannot see emails or they are very faint and when you click on them it shows a completely different email in preview box.
Sometimes you cannot scroll either. I have completed a system restore, changed screen resolutions, updated windows and windows essentials, uninstalled and reinstalled  windows live mail, checked for errors and lastly completed a restore in safe mode but still no change. Can anyone advise?

Comment: What do you mean exactly they appear "faint"?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?